# Setting up two UIPickerviews in one view

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I'm having trouble Setting up two UIPickerviews in one view in my beginner Swift project and I keep getting a `Cannot subscript a value of type '[Range<Int>]'` error and I just can't get my head wrap around what I'm doing wrong. I'm working on this project to learn swift.

```
@IBOutlet weak var hourWorkedPicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var payRatePicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var total: UILabel!


let hoursWorked = [10...60]
let payRate = [9...50]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if pickerView == hourWorkedPicker {
        return hoursWorked.count
    } else { // if it's the second picker view
        return payRate.count
    }
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if pickerView == hourWorkedPicker {
        return hoursWorked[row] //ERORR IS HERE <-----------------------------
    } else {
        return payRate[row] //ERORR IS HERE <--------------------------------
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let hoursWorked = [10...60]
let payRate = [9...50]
```

These are Range variables and not arrays. You can use subscript only for arrays. Hence it failed at

```
return hoursWorked[row]
```

So, you should convert your range to an array.

To convert, you can use something like follows

```
let hoursWorked: [Int] = Array(10...60)
or
let hoursWorked = [Int](10...60)
```

Comment: Since `UIPickerView` title expect string, please add this to modify your return statement to return string. `return String(format: "%d", hoursWorked[row])`

Comment: That worked! Thanks now I just have to figure out why its not populating correctly

Answer (score 0):

Your function expects a return values to be String. Where as you haven't defined them as Array of strings.

Try using

```
let hoursWorked = ["10", "20", "30", "40"];
let payRate = ["9", "10", "11"]
```

If this looks to much effort, build this array programmatically.

Comment: So its needs its to be a String for titleForRow? I'll try to do it programmatically